# F# SQLProvider Columns Order Doesn't match the order in the table

Tags: postgresql, f#

I select from a postgresql view\table and export the values into excel file.

The excel file column order need to be the same as the table, but the sqlProvider select them with abc order...

My Code is:

```
module ViewToExcel

open System
open System.IO
//open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
open System.Drawing
open Npgsql
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open OfficeOpenXml
open Casaubon
open NpgsqlTypes

let [<Literal>] connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=;"
let [<Literal>] npgPath = @"..\packages\Npgsql.3.1.7\lib\net451"

type sqlConnection = SqlDataProvider<ConnectionString = connectionString,
                                        DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL,
                                        ResolutionPath = npgPath,
                                        IndividualsAmount = 1000,
                                        UseOptionTypes = true>
let functionParseViewToExcel (excelPath:string, serverName:string, dbName:string) =


        /////////////////////////////////Get Data Connection///////////////////////
        printf "connect to db\n"

        let connectionUserString = @"Server="+serverName+";Database="+dbName+";User Id=postgres;Password=;"

        let ctx = sqlConnection.GetDataContext(connectionUserString)

        let weekCalcView = ctx.Public.CcVibeWeeklyCalculations

       // weekCalcView|> Seq.toList

        let weekCalcViewSeq = ctx.Public.CcVibeWeeklyCalculations|> Seq.toArray

        ////////////////////////////////// Start Excel//////////////////////////////

        let newExcelFile = FileInfo(excelPath  + "cc_vibe_treatment_period_"+ DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy_dd_MM")+".xlsx");

        if (newExcelFile.Exists) then
           newExcelFile.Delete();

        let pck = new ExcelPackage(newExcelFile);

        //Add the 'xxx' sheet
        let ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("xxx");

        //printf "success to start the excel file\n"

        let mutable columNames = "blabla"
        for col in weekCalcViewSeq.[0].ColumnValues do
            let columnName = match col with |(a, _) -> a
            //printf "a %A\n" columnName
            let columnNamewithPsic = "," + columnName
            columNames <-  columNames + columnNamewithPsic
        ws.Cells.[1, 1].LoadFromText(columNames.Replace("blabla,",""))|> ignore

        ws.Row(1).Style.Fill.PatternType <- Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
        ws.Row(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170))  
        ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold <- true; 
        ws.Row(1).Style.Font.UnderLine <- true;

        let mutable subject = weekCalcViewSeq.[0].StudySubjectLabel.Value // in order to color the rows according to subjects
        let mutable color = 0
        for row in 1.. weekCalcViewSeq.Length do
            let mutable columValues = "blabla"
            for col in weekCalcViewSeq.[row-1].ColumnValues do
                let columnValue = match col with |(_, a) -> a
                //printf "a %A\n" columnValue
                match columnValue with
                | null -> columValues <-  columValues + "," + ""
                | _ -> columValues <-  columValues + "," + columnValue.ToString()            
            ws.Cells.[row + 1, 1].LoadFromText(columValues.Replace("blabla,",""))|> ignore

            /////////////////////Color the row according to subject///////////////


            if (weekCalcViewSeq.[row - 1].StudySubjectLabel.Value = subject) then
                 if (color = 0) then
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.PatternType <- Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(255,255,204)) 
                 else
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.PatternType <- Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White) 
            else
                 subject <- weekCalcViewSeq.[row - 1].StudySubjectLabel.Value
                 if (color = 0) then
                  color <- 1
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.PatternType <- Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White)                 
                 else
                  color <- 0
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.PatternType <- Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
                  ws.Row(row + 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(255,255,204))

 pck.Save()
```

The Excel Output fields is:
bloating_avg,caps_fail,caps_success,date_of_baseline_visit,discomfort_avg and etc...

But the order in the table isn't the same.

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This code is nowhere close to runable in any regard, and as such... In general it might be said, if you want the columns in an specific order, write it in that order explicitly.

Comment: Couldn't I do it generic? for each view with different columns?

Comment: How should I be able to know? And of course the answer is "yes you can do it generic".  How is a totally different matter. I would guess its more than possible to get the actual order of columns et. al. in some regard, but maybe not directly with the SQLProvider. I cant understand why you need to either, so ...

Comment: Thank you for your response. Have an idea with which tool to use?

Comment: Would you mind asking a questions which is not to broad? And if possible write up some code for proof of concept of exactly what you want and how YOU would do it? If you create a script-file with a connection to some DB, creates some tables either programmatically or with some script, and then the minimum code for reading and writing the DB-content again, and then post that code/setup here, then there might be some hope for this case. As it is now it is either to broad a question ("what tool?") or is missing a lot of code/information to replicate/run or even understand the issue at hand. OK?

Comment: ok, thank you, I edited my question. Is it ok now?

Comment: I don't think it's because of the type provider, it's probably PostgreSQL itself. When you examine the table in `pgAdmin` under Schemes, you can see the table columns listed in alphabetical order. Hence it might not be easily doable from within the type provider. Maybe somethin in `npgsql`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small helper function to extract the field (column) names via `npgqsl`. After that you can just use this list of column names to create your excel table. The getColNames function gets it from a DataReader. Obviously you can refactor it further, to get at the tablename as parameter, etc.

```
#r @"..\packages\SQLProvider.1.0.33\lib\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"
#r @"..\packages\Npgsql.3.1.7\lib\net451\Npgsql.dll"

open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql
open Npgsql
open NpgsqlTypes

let conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=root;Database=postgres;Pooling=false")
conn.Open()
let cmd  = new NpgsqlCommand()
cmd.Connection <- conn

cmd.CommandText <- """ SELECT * FROM public."TestTable1" """ 
let recs = cmd.ExecuteReader()

let getColNames (recs:NpgsqlDataReader) =  
    let columns = recs.GetColumnSchema() |> Seq.toList 
    columns |> List.map (fun x -> x.BaseColumnName)

let colnames = getColNames recs
//val colnames : string list = ["ID"; "DT"; "ADAY"]

rec.Dispose()
conn.Dispose()
```

You can see that the column names are not in alphabetical order. You could use this column name list to get at the records in  the correct order. Or just use the Reader object directly without the type provider.

**Edit: Using records to map the table**

It is also possible to extract the data, using the type provider, in the required format, by wiring up the types, and then using `.MapTo<T>`:

```
type DataRec = {
    DT:DateTime 
    ADAY:String 
    ID:System.Int64
    }

type sql = SqlDataProvider<dbVendor,connString2,"",resPath,indivAmount,useOptTypes>
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
let table1 = ctx.Public.TestTable1
let qry = query { for row in table1 do
                  select row} |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.MapTo<DataRec>())
qry |> Seq.toList
```

> val it : DataRec list =   [{DT = 2016/09/27 00:00:00;
>       ADAY = "Tuesday";
>       ID = 8L;}; {DT = 2016/09/26 00:00:00;
>                   ADAY = "Monday";
>                   ID = 9L;}; {DT = 2016/09/25 00:00:00;
>                               ADAY = "Sunday";